# IE11 JQuery ajax caching even with cache:false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, coldfusion

I've tried everything I know and everything I've found to prevent IE (Edge!) from caching:

- `cache:false` within the ajax params
- add (manually) a  timestamp in the call
- set `ajaxSetup`
- change request method from `GET` to `POST`
- return a header inside the AJAX page that was called

I'm not using C# in order to use the param mentioned in some posts (I'm using coldfusion). Does someone know another method in order to fix that IE "feature"?

Here's the AJAX code in case you don't trust in me (like Dr. House says: everybody lies) or I'm skipping something:

```
$('a#showLista').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'cfc/carrito.cfc?' + (new Date()).getTime() + '&method=preciosListaFav',
        cache: false,
        countentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            DataSource: DataSource,
            IDCliente: clienteID,
            IDUsuario: IDUsuario,
            Sesion: Sesion
        },
        success: function(datos) {
            i = datos.DATA.length;
            if (i > 0) {
                // Insert data into table
            } else
                // Alert empty list                     
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the caching issue is on the client and not the server?

Comment: Highly doubt it is the client...

Comment: POST doesn't cache, and neither do unique URLs; look elsewhere. GIGO.

Comment: unrelated, but... `countentType`(typ0) and your contentType value is wrong for your data.

Comment: Can you show us your network tab results for this request?

Comment: It works well in other browsers, so I dont' think it's server side caché... but I'll ask the manager anyway.

Comment: What's the status code of the response? Does the response contain a reidrect? After clearing the cache, how long does it take to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Status code was 200... but @epascarello and the others were right: It was not the client.... I'm really really sorry for not noticing that before, but sometimes you need that someone shows what's 'outside your box'. Thanks all of you for your time. You gauys are the real MVP's